# I want to count number of space from textbox and store it in array

Tags: vb.net

I want to count space from textbox and an array should be there its length should be equal to number of space and store each word to array

Comment: I have done code for space but i dont know how to store each word to areay

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Dim words() As String = Textbox.Text.Split()
```

If you need to check each word for any reason:

```
 For a = 0 To words.Length - 1

 ' do your stuff here

 Next
```

Comment: Let me explain it more , what ever words are in textbox it should be seperatw by space and. Store in array each word and after that it should search for keyword each word in database or library that whether it is there or not and display that it is there or not

Comment: By default Split() uses space in no character(s) are entered.  You can also specify the character at which the split must happen such as Split("b"), but you should keep in mind that the character where the split occurs is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regular Explessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx) and convert result to string array.

```
Dim matches() As String = Regex.Matches("Your string for testing", "\S+") _
    .OfType(Of Match)() _
    .Select(Function(m As Match) m.Value) _
    .ToArray()
' matches(0) is "Your"
' matches(1) is "string"
' matches(2) is "for"
' matches(3) is "testing"
```

To repeats any actions for each element in the `matches` collection use For-Each loop:

```
For Each match As String In matches
    ' Do something with match variable
Next
```

To use `Regex` class you need to import `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

Comment: Tanx for your help but can u show the full code i mean what i do next ? Sorry i am beginner in vb

Comment: @Klaus, what do you want to do with `matches()` array?

Comment: I want it to search in database or library that i jave created for keyword whether it is in data base or not

Comment: @Klaus I have added `For Each ... Next` example to my answer, but while I don't see your code I don`t help you. You could create new question [with detailed description](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of your trouble.

Comment: Dim n as integer                                                                             n = 0                                                                                     Dim i as string = txtbox1.text                                                  For each wrd as char in i                                                                 If wrd = " " then                                                                   n += 1                                                                                   End if

Comment: @Klaus, run example in debug mode and watch how `match` variable changing.  To work with real string from your textbox use `txtbox1.text` instead of `"Your string for testing"`.